# splash screen to choose pincode by user

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml

I want to add splash screen which includes choice to select pincode required by user,, then it displays homepage. I want details how and where to add code in magento files.. I don want to use any extension. Please guide me correct path.
reference: http://www.awesomeji.com/cadbury-s/
Reloading page should appear as below link
https://ihatetomatoes.net/create-custom-preloading-screen/